# how to keep inserting data continuous in second column if first column already inserted more than second

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Hello friends please help to create coding against this little problem if possible:

I have a table which contains 4 columns:

| id | course | college | branch |

If we entered value in college column upto 10 value and in course we entered 4 value and in branch we enter 1 value so finally we entered 10 id

[image]

suppose I want to enter data in id(6,7,8,9,10,11,12) in column name: college , without gap

database name is "test" and table name is "admin_data"

I m using:

```
<?php
include "db.php";

if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
foreach ($_POST['course'] as $course) {
    $data1 = mysql_real_escape_string($course);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO admin_data (course) VALUES ('$data1')") or            die(mysql_error());
}
}

if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
foreach ($_POST['college'] as $college) {
    $data2 = mysql_real_escape_string($college);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO admin_data (college) VALUES ('$data2')") or   die(mysql_error());
}
}

if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
foreach ($_POST['branch'] as $branch) {
    $data1 = mysql_real_escape_string($branch);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO admin_data (branch) VALUES ('$data3')") or    die(mysql_error());
}
}
header("location: data_enter.php");

?>
```

But not getting proper sollution....:(

Comment: That doesn't look normalized to me.

Comment: hello sir if you have anyy suggestion plz tell me ...

Comment: Do you want to modify the rows you have highlighted, or create new ones? If you want to modify, then you will need to use `UPDATE` instead, with a `WHERE` clause against `id`.

Comment: Yes, normalize your data.

Comment: Sir i want to insert 6 more row from 7 to 12 anyhow,If we will use Update then we cannot enter more than 10 id but if we use insert then it will continue from 11 (ids)

Comment: Hi there. A couple of items of assistance for you: firstly, don't post code or error messages as images, as it makes it impossible for the search engines to help people find similar problems. Secondly, if you have additional details, edit your question, rather than making an answer. That error message looks like it is worth knowing about. So, it may be worth updating your question, code and error, by editing it, so that people can see the new state of your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I couldnt understand your question properly but why don't you just add data in once like

```
 "INSERT INTO admin_data (course,college,branch) VALUES ('$data1','$data2','$data3')"
```

This way you will not leave any empty cells or gaps. and if still you want to fill empty cells then i would suggest this query

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
     $data1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['course']);
     mysql_query("update admin_data set course = $data1 where id = (select id from admin_data where course = null limit 1);");
}
```

Note: don't use obselet MySQL move to PDO and MySQLi.

Comment: this is not working...

Comment: what problem you are getting?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: course in F:\GoogleDrive\www\search engine\data_entry.php on line 5

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in F:\GoogleDrive\www\search engine\data_entry.php on line 5
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from admin_data set course = asd where id = (select id from admin_data where cou' at line 1

Comment: well you are writting wrong query. show me your complete query

Comment: "update admin_data set course = $data2 where id = (select id from admin_data where course = null limit 1)"

Comment: Well your query is correct perhaps may be it's your code. Plz show us your code screen shot so we can trace error.

Comment: exactly your query is correct show us your code dear

Comment: Why you use foreach? just try simple code. Let me edit my code

Comment: look i have updated my above code and try it.

Comment: have you got you code working now?

Comment: You didn't replied that did you get your answer?